# Where's the smart group profiler in 5.67?

Tags: smartgroups

The release notes for 5.67 says 'Smart groups: a smart group profiler was added to help identify slow smart groups'.  Where is this profiler? - I can't see it in the menu, and it doesn't seem to be an extension.

Answer (score 1):

Set CIVICRM_SLOW_SMART_GROUP_SECONDS to 5 or something in civicrm.settings.php and then whenever the smart group cache is filled it will log warnings in ConfigAndLog when a group takes longer than that to compute.

Comment: sounds very helpful - i had cooked up a SK table to show this but much more usfeul in the logs.